# Getting [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it> error while executing RF code

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I'm executing a robot framework script in Windows 10 machine and I'm getting a error : "**URLError:**  ". Not even the browser is getting opened. Can anyone help me out!!!

Comment: I'm executing the script in windows 10 machine with eclipse IDE

Comment: what you are doing in code?

Comment: I will open a browser and hit the application URL then I will be entering the credentials.

Comment: Gecko/chromedriver/edgedriver installed and up-to-date, and the system firewall doesn't block the connections in the path selenium<->driver<->browser?

Comment: could you please share the code you tried. Error seems to be issue with URL you are using.`Open Browser    <URL>    <BROWSER>`

Comment: # ${dc}   Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER  sys, selenium.webdriver
    # Set To Dictionary    ${dc}  useLegacyInternalServer    ${True}
     Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}

Comment: Issue is resolved. I used this code "Set Environment Variable     no_proxy     127.0.0.1" now I'm able to launch the browser and hit the URL in IE.